# How to extract all lines in file1 that match a pattern in another file2 by awk?

Tags: bash, awk

file1:

```
chr1    11868   14409   ENST00000456328.2   0   +   11868   11868   0   3   359,109,1189,   0,744,1352,
chr1    12009   13670   ENST00000450305.2   0   +   12009   12009   0   6   48,49,85,78,154,218,    0,169,603,965,1211,1443,
chr1    14403   29570   ENST00000488147.1   0   -   14403   14403   0   11  98,34,152,159,198,136,137,147,99,154,37,    0,601,1392,2203,2454,2829,3202,3511,3864,10334,15130,
chr1    17368   17436   ENST00000619216.1   0   -   17368   17368   0   1   68, 0,
chr1    29553   31097   ENST00000473358.1   0   +   29553   29553   0   3   486,104,122,    0,1010,1422,
chr1    30266   31109   ENST00000469289.1   0   +   30266   30266   0   2   401,134,    0,709,
chr1    30365   30503   ENST00000607096.1   0   +   30365   30365   0   1   138,    0,
chr1    34553   36081   ENST00000417324.1   0   -   34553   34553   0   3   621,205,361,    0,723,1167,
chr1    35244   36073   ENST00000461467.1   0   -   35244   35244   0   2   237,353,    0,476,
chr1    52472   53312   ENST00000606857.1   0   +   52472   52472   0   1   840,    0,
```

file2:

```
ENST00000456328
ENST00000450305
```

Expected output:

```
chr1    11868   14409   ENST00000456328.2   0   +   11868   11868   0   3   359,109,1189,   0,744,1352,
chr1    12009   13670   ENST00000450305.2   0   +   12009   12009   0   6   48,49,85,78,154,218,    0,169,603,965,1211,1443,
```

I'd prefer to use awk or some other bash program.

Comment: `grep -f file2 file1`?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks @jesse_b. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is the perfect one :

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

If you still prefer to use **awk** :

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $1;next} { split($4,key,"."); if ( a[key[1]]){print}}' file2 file1
```

Using simple for loop ( same as what first grep would do ) :

```
for match in $(<file2); do grep $match file1; done
```

Comment: Thanks, Stalin! I am wondering could "awk" is more time saving compared with "grep"? Since when I run "grep", it took a pretty long time to finish on my Mac.

Comment: @Weiyan : Pleasure, Thanks! Not always , for simple search grep is faster than any other stream line / file parser .Awk is better for reports formatting and computing values for each line.Each has its unique usage.Its Us to decide which is better for our implementation.

Comment: great explanation and thank you again

Comment: I think there is a typo in your `awk` command line: the single-quote `'` should be _before_ the `FNR==NR` condition.

Comment: @AdminBee , I testted it , works fine bro !!! Thanks...

Comment: Yes, but this is only because you happened to have no space between `FNR==NR` and the remaining `awk` instructions enclosed in `'...'`, and the fact that the shell then interpreted this as one single string token made it (still) work. `awk` does not require that conditions precede the action block without space, and if you had typed `awk FNR==NR '{<etc.>} { <etc.>}' file2 file1` you would have got an error. I recommend correcting that, bc if someone new to `awk` sees this they may be confused/stumble on strange behavior if they adopt this "style" (which would be sad, it's an elegant answer).

Comment: Yeah right! Done bro , i have changed it now...thanks for notifying me !!!